# Better way to swap two adjacent words in a PERL string?

Tags: regex, perl

I had an odd case where I typed in two names wrong in a game I was writing. They mirror each other. For instance,  there are Henry Patrick and Patrick Henry, and I wanted to swap them in a mistaken chunk of code I wrote.

Now the PERL code below does so, but the temporary replacement string `heinous-hack-string` is, well, a hack. Is there a more elegant way to do things?

```
##################
#nameflip.pl
#
# this flips names where I mistakenly switched first-last and last-first
#

use strict;
use warnings;

my $mystr = "There's this guy named Henry Patrick, and there's another guy named Patrick Henry, " . 
  "and I confused them and need to switch them now!";

print "Before: $mystr\n";

print "After: " . stringNameSwitch($mystr, "Patrick", "Henry") . "\n";

##############################
# awful hack of a subroutine.
#
# what regex would do better?
#
# right now I just want to switch (name1 name2) <=> (name2 name1)

sub stringNameSwitch
{
  my $temp = $_[0];
  $temp =~ s/$_[1] +$_[2]/heinous-hack-string/i;
  $temp =~ s/$_[2] +$_[1]/$_[1] $_[2]/i;
  $temp =~ s/heinous-hack-string/$_[2] $_[1]/i;
  return $temp;
}
```

Comment: `$mystr =~ s/\b(Patrick|Henry)(\s+)(Henry|Patrick)\b/$3$2$1/g;`

Comment: I think I considered that and rejected it. I was worried it would flip all 4 possibilities, but flipping "Henry Henry" of course wouldn't matter. So, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this, perhaps? The *branch reset* construct `(?|...)` allows the two names to be  captured into `$1` and `$2` regardless of their order of appearance.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $mystr = <<END;
There's this guy named Henry Patrick,
and there's another guy named Patrick Henry,
and I confused them and need to switch them now!
END

print name_switch($mystr, qw/ Henry Patrick /);

sub name_switch {
    my ($s, $n1, $n2) = @_;

    $s =~ s/\b(?|($n1)\s+($n2)|($n2)\s+($n1))\b/$2 $1/gr;
}
```

#### output

```
There's this guy named Patrick Henry,
and there's another guy named Henry Patrick,
and I confused them and need to switch them now!
```

Comment: You could also capture the whitespace in the middle to preserve formatting: `($n1)(\s+)($n2)|($n2)(\s+)($n1)` ... `$3$2$1`

Comment: Thanks much! I'd recently cribbed from another question to get this code: `if ($a =~ /\[start(?! of)/i)` (I wanted to flag "start" without "of" after in certain code sections) and your explanation filled in several follow up questions I could've/should've asked earlier.